# Pedal thread gone SRAM 150/100 chainset - what can be done?

Tags: crankset, pedals

I recently bought an Eastway FB3.0 road bike (http://www.wiggle.co.uk/eastway-fb30-2014/) for commuting and the pedal thread has gone on the right hand pedal.

Am I right in thinking the only solution is to buy another crankset?

The problem is the crankset (SRAM 150) on the bike doesn't seem to on sale anymore. Ideally I'd like to go to a shop in the morning and buy something similar in price and fit it.

If I was to get a Shimano cranset, I assume I would also need to replace the bottom bracket. Is this possible? And is it an easy thing to replace?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to [helicoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_insert) the crankset. This is an insert which can be used to repair threading, though you need some special tools to do it. Your bike shop may or may not have this as an option. They may charge you as much as dropping in a new SRAM S100 crankset for this.

The crankset uses a Powerspline BB (which means if you to keep the BB, you're going to have to use a SRAM crankset and it seems like your only option is the SRAM S100).

You can replace the bottom bracket (BB) with any [conventional threaded](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/) type and use correspondingly compatible crank. For Shimano, you'll get a Hollowtech II bottom bracket for most mid range or higher cranks and a square taper or octalink for the lower end. Note there are other companies which you might want to look for cranks as well (e.g. FSA).

Your bike shop will be able to guide you on this depending on what they have in stock and your price range. It's an easy job to replace the crank or put in a new bottom bracket, but you need the right BB tool, a large crescent wrench and a crank puller.

Comment: If your local bike shop cannot insert the Helicoil, a nearby machine shop may be able to.

Comment: Auto mechanics should have the right tap and stuff as well (for the right pedal at least; I think only bicycle mechanics will have the stuff for the left pedal) -- you're looking for 9/16" with 20 tpi, which some spark plugs use. Whether they'd do it for you or not is a different matter. As far as I know though, most bike shops will go for replacing the crankset rather than installing the helicoil. I suspect it will be more economical that way too when you take into account labor.